# Не получается Десериализовать файл json: string в DateTime

Tags: c#, json, десериализация

У меня есть вот такой Json файлик:

```json
[
  {
    "Date": "1950",
    "someEvent": "Cold world"
  },
  {
    "Date": "1991-06-01",
    "someEvent": "какое-то событие 2"
  },
  {
    "Date": "2000-01-01",
    "someEvent": "наступил миллениум, ура-ура-ура"
  },
  {
    "Date": "2021",
    "someEvent": "Still cold world"
  }
]
```

Также помимо него в моей программе есть класс Event:

```cs
public class Event 
{   
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}
```

Когда я пытаюсь сделать десериализацию:

```cs
public static Event[] JsonTimeline() // Считывает данные из файла с событиями
{
    string str = File.ReadAllText(@"timeline.json");
    Event[] time = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Event[]>(str);
    return time;
}
```

Появляется ошибка, которая мне сообщает, что 1950, т.е string, нельзя привести к DateTime, хотя для другого класса, который тоже имеет DateTime свойство всё работает. В чём моя проблема?

Comment: В таких случаях используют кастомные конвертеры

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте подправить класс :

```
public class Event
{
    [JsonPropertyName("Date")]
    public string Date { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("someEvent")]
    public string SomeEvent { get; set; }

    private DateTime GetDateTime() => 
        DateTime.ParseExact(Date, "yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

}
```

Можете попробовать создать консольное приложение и конвертировать string "1950" в DateTime. Не думаю, что Convert.ToDateTime поможет.

Не знаю, как там точно под капотом десериализатора, но не думаю, что там вызов какого-то подобного метода. Обычными способами Convert.ToDateTime или подобными у вас вряд ли получится так просто конвертировать эту строку в дату.

https://json2csharp.com/ - вот ссылочка на полезный сайт, который может первое время помочь с созданием правильного класса. Конечно, на 200% на него надеяться не стоит, но как "помощник" стоит рассмотреть.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Без JsonPropertyName:

```
public class Event
{
    public string Date { get; set; }

    public string someEvent { get; set; }

    private DateTime GetDateTime() => 
        DateTime.ParseExact(Date, "yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Comment: `JsonPropertyName` это `System.Text.Json`, а у автора другая либа. И смысл добавлять аттрибут, если имя свойства совпадает с полем в json?

Comment: У меня привычка добавлять аттрибуты, если нужно десериализовать. Просто визуально так легче читается код. Я в последнее время стараюсь много сил уделять стилю кода, его читабельности и тп, поэтому, как по мне, стоит оставить аттрибуты

Comment: нет конечно. Никогда код с кучей атрибутов не будет читаться легче, чем без. Но я вам про другое написал, в первую очередь.

Comment: Разве? Хорошо, я почитаю об этом моменте чуть больше информации. Мне всегда казалось, что атрибуты как раз таки помогают в читабельности. Касаемо JsonPropertyName - дополнил ответ и добавил в него вариант без этого. Потестил - всё отлично работает.

Comment: Еще раз, автор не использует `System.Text.Json`, он использует `Newtonsoft.Json`. Ваши атрибуты ему не подходят.

Comment: Как заметили выше, всё так, такой вариант не подходит